# Symfony differentiate application by dynamic route prefix

Tags: symfony, routes

I need to differentiate what data to load by route prefix.

Let's say that I have these routes:

- `http://test.com/app1/news`
- `http://test.com/app1/gallery`
- `http://test.com/app2/news`
- `http://test.com/app2/gallery`
- `http://test.com/app3/news`
- `http://test.com/app3/gallery`

URL of apps (`app1, app2, app3`) are saved in database. For each app, there are different data for news, gallery etc.

Is there any way how to "cache" app entity and do not load it every time from database and check prefix in every action in controllers?
Is it good idea to save app object to session (and change it only if URL is changed)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use Doctrine ORM you can configure second level cache.
More Information in link [Doctrine second-level-cache](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/second-level-cache.html)